# Redirect Component in NextJs

Tags: next.js

I am working on a project using NextJS and I need a Redirect component

I don't want to use the `next/router` api as I am forced to execute it within `useEffect`.

My use case is that if a user hasn't logged in, he should be redirected immediately to the login page without seeing the home page at all.

If I use `next/router`, he somehow sees the home page first before the redirect happens. I don't want that behavior.

Here is the code I currently have

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import UserManager from '../../managers/user_manager';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function UserHome(props) {

    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!UserManager.getLoggedInUser()) {
            router.push("/auth/login"); /***It turns out that before this happens, the user has already seen some parts of the home page. Too bad.***/
        }
    });

    return (<div>
        Home Page
    </div>);
}
```

I'll rather prefer something like this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import UserManager from '../../managers/user_manager';

export default function UserHome(props) {    
    return (
                <div>
                {
                  !UserManager.getLoggedInUser() && <Redirect to="/auth/login"/>
                }
                <RealHomePage/>
                </div>
           );
}
```

but unfortunately it seems nextjs doesn't have a `Redirect` component.
What other alternative can I employ here so the user doesn't see my home page before I finally redirect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) technic to develop the force authentication pages
like the profile page, read this code:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function AuthenticationHOC({ children }) {
  // get token from everywhere you want
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  const Router = useRouter();

  if (token) {
    // render profile page
    return children;
  }
  return Router.push("/login");
}
```